# libgdx: Why doesnt my InputAdapter receive the keyUp event?

Tags: java, libgdx, keyup

I'm recreating a Pokemon Game with libgdx, and I have an InputAdapter that controlls the player movement, and it works fine. Then I have this other InputAdapter to controll an OptionBox i created where options are shown. (For example this Boy/Girl options in Pokemon), but it doesnt work at all. I added a System.out.println inside the keyUp method to check if it pops but it doesnt. Does anyone know why?

```
public class OptionBoxController extends InputAdapter {

    private OptionBox optionBox;

    public OptionBoxController(OptionBox optionBox) {
        this.optionBox = optionBox;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Keys.UP) {
            optionBox.moveUp();
        } else if (keycode == Keys.DOWN) {
            optionBox.moveDown();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I implement this both InputAdapters in my Screen like this:

```
multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

playerController = new PlayerController(player);
optionBoxController = new OptionBoxController(optionBox);
multiplexer.addProcessor(0, playerController);
multiplexer.addProcessor(1, optionBoxController);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really stupid I just discovered why it didnt work, it was because in my `show()`method in my Screen class, i had `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(playerController);` instead of `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);`so only my playerController was actually working. I'll leave this post here just in case someone has the same problem.